# Using ncurses extended character from struct

Tags: c++, struct, character-encoding, ncurses

I'm trying to display ncurses extended characters that I'm pulling from a struct.

When I try to use:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    char    nCharacter;     // Where I want to store variable for printed character
    short   nTestNumber;    // Other stuff in struct
};
TEST_STRUCT sTestData[] = {
    { '.', 1 },         // Period
    { ',', 2 },         // Comma
    { ACS_VLINE, 1 }    // Vertical Line
};
int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    clear();
    for( int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    {
        addch(sTestData[n].nCharacter); // print the characters in the struct
    }
        refresh();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

the ACS_VLINE character isn't displayed properly, but after messing around a little, I found the following works:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
struct TEST_STRUCT
{
    int     nCharacter;         // Where I want to store variable for printed character
    short   nTestNumber;    // Other stuff in struct
};
TEST_STRUCT sTestData[] = {
    { '.', 1 },     // Period
    { ',', 2 },     // Comma
    { 4194424, 1 }  // Vertical Line
};
int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    clear();
    for( int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    {
        addch(sTestData[n].nCharacter);     // print the characters in the struct
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Storing a numerical value in an int seems wrong for this, but it works. How should I be doing this to be doing it "correctly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your first example is that the symbol `ACS_VLINE` is an entry in an array which is not initialized statically (its actual contents depend upon `initscr`).  Oddly, g++ does not warn about that, but `gcc -Wall` does warn.

That's defined something like this:

```
#define NCURSES_ACS(c)  (acs_map[NCURSES_CAST(unsigned char,c)])

#define ACS_VLINE       NCURSES_ACS('x') /* vertical line */
```

The constant in the second case is different, amounting to `A_ALTCHARSET` combined with `x`:

```
#define NCURSES_ATTR_SHIFT       8
#define NCURSES_BITS(mask,shift) ((mask) << ((shift) + NCURSES_ATTR_SHIFT))

#define A_ALTCHARSET    NCURSES_BITS(1UL,14)
```

That's been a distinction since the early 2000s, as hinted in the [changelog from 2003](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20030419).